# document.getelementbyid().value doesnt work

Tags: javascript, laravel, forms, laravel-blade, getelementbyid

this in my form, i just several items in my form related to script that i use, script down below

```html
<div class="form-group form-float">
  <div class="form-line">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pembiayaan" id="jumlah" min="1" max="50" value=""
      autocomplete="pembiayaan" autofocus required>
    <label class="form-label">Jumlah Pembiayaan</label>
  </div>
  <div class="help-info">Min. 1, Max. 50 characters</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-float">

  <strong>Kegunaan:</strong>
  <select name="kegunaan" id="kegunaan">

    <option value="Modal Kerja" selected>Modal Kerja</option>
    <option value="Investasi">Investasi</option>
    <option value="Konsumtif">Konsumtif</option>



  </select>

</div>
<div class="form-group form-float">
  <div class="form-line">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="objek_pembiayaan" min="1" max="50" value=""
      autocomplete="objek_pembiayaan" autofocus required>
    <label class="form-label">Objek Pembiayaan</label>
  </div>
  <div class="help-info">Min. 1, Max. 50 characters</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-float">

  <strong>Jenis Pembiayaan:</strong>
  <select name="jenis" id="jenis">

    <option value="Murabahah" selected>Murabahah</option>
    <option value="Qardh" disabled>Qardh</option>
    <option value="Mudharabah" disabled>Mudharabah</option>
    <option value="Musyarakah" disabled>Musyarakah</option>
    <option value="Qardul Hasan" disabled>Qardul Hasan</option>

  </select>

</div>
<div class="form-group form-float">
  <div class="form-line">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="jangka_waktu" min="1" max="50" id="waktu" value=""
      autocomplete="jangka_waktu" autofocus required>
    <label class="form-label">Jangka Waktu (Bulan)</label>
  </div>
  <div class="help-info">Min. 1, Max. 50 characters</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-float">
  <div class="form-line">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sistem_pembayaran" min="1" max="50" value="Tunai" disabled>
    <label class="form-label">Sistem Pembayaran</label>
  </div>
  <div class="help-info">Min. 1, Max. 50 characters</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-float">
  <div class="form-line">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="margin" id="margin" min="1" max="50" value="2%" disabled>
    <label class="form-label">Margin</label>
  </div>
  <div class="help-info">Min. 1, Max. 50 characters</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group form-float">
  <div class="form-line">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nisbah" id="nisbah" min="1" max="50" value="">
    <label class="form-label">Nisbah</label>
  </div>
  <div class="help-info">Min. 1, Max. 50 characters</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-float">
  <div class="form-line">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="total" id="total" min="1" max="50" value="">
    <label class="form-label">Total</label>
  </div>
  <div class="help-info">Min. 1, Max. 50 characters</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group form-float">
  <div class="form-line">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="angsuran" id="angsuran" min="1" max="50" value="">
    <label class="form-label">Angsuran per Bulan</label>
  </div>
  <div class="help-info">Min. 1, Max. 50 characters</div>
</div>
```

this is my script

```js
function hitunghargajual() {
  var jumlah = parseInt(document.getElementById('jumlah').value);
  var waktu = parseInt(document.getElementById('waktu').value);
  var margin = 0.02;
  var nisbah = jumlah * margin;
  var total = jumlah + nisbah;
  var angsuran = total / waktu;

  if (harga != null) {
    document.getElementById('nisbah').value = nisbah;
    document.getElementById('total').value = total;
    document.getElementById('angsuran').value = angsuran;
  }
  else {
    alert("Masukkan Nilai yang Valid!");
  }
}
```

I have put right id, how its not working?, im trying to do math but nothing happen, its not showing anything

Comment: i cant find jumlah id in html code

Comment: What's "harga" refering to ? Maybe you simply never enter the condition... Did you try alert() something after if(harga != null){ ?

Comment: <div class="form-group form-float">
                                    <div class="form-line">
                                        <input id="jumlah" type="text" class="form-control" name="pembiayaan"  min="1" max="50" value="" autocomplete="pembiayaan" autofocus required>
                                        <label class="form-label">Jumlah Pembiayaan</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="help-info">Min. 1, Max. 50 characters</div>
                                </div>

Comment: Do you run that function `hitunghargajual()` somewhere? Also, please don't post code in the comments, hard to read etc. Instead, [edit] your question and paste relevant data there. Thx

Comment: Did you check your browser's debug console? You can get there e. g. by pressing F12 in Firefox. If there are any error messages in the console, try to fix them or add them to your question!

Answer (score -1):

thaks for all, i forgot to harga "harga" to 'jumlah'